# Ubuntu 18.04 frequent crashing and instability

Tags: 18.04, crash

my installation of Ubuntu 18.04 has been working fine for a few weeks but in the last two days has become unstable and crashes frequently, typically within minutes/an hour after startup. I have to do a hard reset each time.

Here is the last half hour or so from my syslog: https://pastebin.com/Gm0yZvyD.

I think it might have something to do with an encrypted ext4 4TB internal hard drive that I use to store my data. I have booted into an install USB and selected the try ubuntu before installation option. Even then when I try to copy some files from my 4TB drive the system totally freezes up.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out I had a faulty RAM chip which was causing all sorts of random errors and general system instability. I diagnosed this with memtest64.